# yii2, skip empty fields in query

Tags: yii2

Could not find any examples on how to do this, but im building a query where it can happen that the column is empty, if empty skip this row.

It should skip when the translation does not have any value(is empty)

```
  $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
  ->select(['a.id',
  'b.filter_item_id',
  'c.id as fid',
  'c.filter_id',
  'd.translation'//skip when this has no value
  ])
  ->from(['a' => 'product'])
  ->leftJoin( ['b' => 'product_filter_item'] ,
               'b.product_id = a.id ')
  ->leftJoin( ['c' => 'filter_item'] ,
               'c.filter_id = b.filter_item_id ')
  ->leftJoin( ['d' => 'filter_item_translation'] ,
               'd.filter_item_id = c.id AND d.attribute = "name" AND 
                d.language = "en"')
  ->all();
```

Comment: if you add it into the on condition of the join does it work ? `->leftJoin( ['d' => 'filter_item_translation'] ,
               'd.filter_item_id = c.id AND d.attribute = "name" AND 
                d.language = "en" and d.translation !== ""')`

Comment: it should be `!=` or `<>` rather than `!=` i just wrote it in the `php` way and copy pasted to the answer too thought you might know about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add in on condition into the `join` for `filter_item_translation`

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
  ->select(['a.id',
  'b.filter_item_id',
  'c.id as fid',
  'c.filter_id',
  'd.translation'//skip when this has no value
  ])
  ->from(['a' => 'product'])
  ->leftJoin( ['b' => 'product_filter_item'] ,
               'b.product_id = a.id ')
  ->leftJoin( ['c' => 'filter_item'] ,
               'c.filter_id = b.filter_item_id ')
  ->leftJoin( ['d' => 'filter_item_translation'] ,
               'd.filter_item_id = c.id AND d.attribute = "name" AND 
                d.language = "en" and d.translation != ""')
  ->all();
```

Comment: `!==` is not a standard SQL operator, are you sure that it works?

Comment: sorry @rob006 it should be `!=` or `<>` i just went into php flow just fixed